# Trying to get an enviroment variable in python, not working

Tags: python, environment-variables

Say I do this in the terminal

```
TEST="abc"
```

A python script run after this (same session, variable is definitely still there) raises a `KeyError` as the key `TEST` doesn't exist. How do I access this environment variable?

```
import os
print os.environ["TEST"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# bash
export TEST=abc

# sh
TEST=abc
export TEST
```

Make sure to export the variable. By default environment variables are not inherited by child processes. Marking them as exported tells the shell to pass them to its children.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal, do

```
export TEST="abc"
```